# Creating extensions for Adobe air

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air

I'm creating an Java extension for the Adobe AIR android app. I'm very new to Adobe flash. I don't have the flash builder, but only flashdevelop IDE. I follow the instructions from [Adobe article to create extensions](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/ane-android-devices.html). The tutorial is very helpful, but unfortunately this is based on Flash Builder.

Step 1 : Create the jar file with the java code -> I did this.

Step 2 : Create an SWC file which is a wrapper to the jar file created in step 1. This is where I'm stuck. I tried to use the [ExportSWC4.2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/exportswc/files/exportswc/ExportSWC%204.2/) component, but this was not successful. Then now I'm trying to use the [`compc`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7fd2.html) utility coming with the SDK. In both of these methods, I'm stuck with the problem that I don't know how to include the jar file created in step 1 in the build of the swc using compc. So, I always get the error in my extension as3 file from the wrapper project about the missing java package/extensions.

My current build command is something like :

```
compc -source-path . -include-classes ....  -output ....
```

So my question is : How can I indicate the compc compiler that it should refer my .jar file?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You don't include a .jar in the build of the swc at all. The swc is only one part of the required components for creating a ANE. Once the swc is created you'll need to extract the library.swf from it. That library.swf needs to be included for each target platform (usually in its own folder) specified by the extension.xml.

Comment: Thanks for the answer BotMaster. Later I realized that the error I was not getting was not due to not included .jar file. The java extension usage happened only during runtime. But I'm not sure if I would be able to get it up and running only with FlashDevelop. So, trying to get hold of a version of Flash Builder now.

Comment: you really only need the Flex or AIR SDK but in that case compiling the swc will be done via command line. With FB 4.7 you can do it easily with an Actionscript Library Project.